# How to add such back button to MainActivity layout?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

I can add a back button on the toolbox but here it is as transparent. But how to add such back button to MainActivity layout?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

1. Set theme NoActionBar to your MainActivity
2. Create custom action bar with custom required back button
3. add onClick listener on that back button and call the finish() function to achieve back functionality.